# How to use custom maps in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, sdk

I'm new to Android maps. I wish to use custom maps like snazzy maps not Google map. I wish to use private map sdk's. But I have no idea. Can anyone guide me or provide any  link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798797/how-to-display-a-custom-map-on-android

Comment: Did you solved your problem yet ?

Answer (score 1):

> Mapbox is built on vector maps, an advanced approach to mapping where
>   data is delivered to the device and precisely rendered in real-time.

Today `Mapbox` joins the other 80% of mobile devices .

Please Check out  [GitHUb](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo) Link

For more details you can [This](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-android-sdk/) Article .